# google codejam shows python runtime error

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is for the Google codejam competition. The below code is compiling correctly on my PC and gives the correct result for the sample code. However it is showing runtime error whenever I try to run it on the google website. I have been messing with it for one hour and still have no idea what's wrong with it.

```
def reversort(reverList):
    global totalScore
    length = len(reverList)
    score = 0

    for i in range(length - 1):
        minimum = reverList.index(min(reverList[i: ]))
        tempList = reverList[i:minimum + 1]
        tempList.reverse()
        reverList[i: minimum + 1] = tempList
        score += minimum - i + 1
    
    totalScore.append(score)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = int(input())
    totalScore = []
    rev = []

    for i in range(t):
        n = int(input())
        apen = []
        for j in range(n):
            apen.append(int(input()))
        reversort(apen)
        print("Case #{}: {}".format(i+1,totalScore[i]))
        rev.append(apen)
```

Comment: Not familiar with Google Code Jam, but iirc most competitions like it require reading from a file, not stdin

Comment: @Nosrep As far as I know for C++ the inputs can be read using std::cin. So I think I should be able to read them using input(). Still I will double check it to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
reverse = int(input())
for i in range(1, reverse + 1):
a = int(input())
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
out = 0
for index in range(a-1):
    min_index = b.index(min(b[index:a]))
    b[index: min_index + 1] = reversed(b[index: min_index + 1])
    out += (min_index) - (index) + 1
print("Case #{}: {}".format(i, out))
```

Comment: Ok so it has sending the input as a whole line. I was using multiple inputs, I think that was causing the runtime error. Thanks